# Rails 6, standalone Jbuilder in a service : partials not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-6, jbuilder

I thought I could use Jbuilder outside of Rails controllers. The documentation said so.

I wrote this module, to include into a service object. Which is integrated in a Rails 6 api app, but is not inheriting from ActiveRecord.

```
module JsonGenerator
  def to_json
    template = File.read("#{::Rails.root}/path/to/template.json.jbuilder")
    Jbuilder.new { |json| eval template }.target!
  end
end
```

```
class Converter::Album
  include JsonGenerator
end
```

This is working if I don't use any partial. But when I do, using a syntax like this:

```
json.artists artists do |artist|
  json.partial! 'artist', artist: artist
end
```

I get this error :

```
Failure/Error: eval template

TypeError:
{:artist=>#<Converter::Artist:0x00007fd0d1a99dc8 @name="Bob">} is not a symbol nor a string
```

The problem seems to be that Jbuilder partials can't accept PORO as argument ?

I don't want to use `eval` anyway, but it's the only way I found for loading a template which is not in the `views` folder.

If I copy paste all my template directly as an argument to the `Jbuilder.new` method, I get the same error.

**Update 04/12/2019**

I tried this line

```
json.partial! partial: 'artist', locals: { artist: artist }
```

and even though it loads the partial, the data it generates is wrong.

I get this

```
"artists" => [{"partial!"=>{"locals"=>{"name"=>"Bob", "instrument"=>"piano"}, "partial"=>"artist"}}]
```

instead of

```
"artists" => [{"name"=>"Bob", "instrument"=>"piano"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason it seems like you have to explicitely name the args when outside rails magic:

```
json.partial! partial: 'artist', locals: { artist: artist }
```

To avoid the eval, I would try something with the rendered (untested):

```
def to_json
  ApplicationController.render(template: 'albums/show.json.jbuilder', assigns: { album: self }, formats: [:json], handlers: [:builder])
end
```

Or with the new renderer:

```
  def to_json
    renderer = ApplicationController.new
    renderer.render('albums/show.json.jbuilder', locals: { album: self }, formats: [:json], handlers: [:builder])
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that don't work, the partial in rendered but the content is wrong. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I could use Jbuilder outside of Rails controllers. The
>   documentation said so.

You can, but not all of the methods you can use within the view context are available.  This is because they are actually two different objects, [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/master/lib/jbuilder.rb) and [JbuilderTemplate](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/master/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb), the latter of which accepts a `context` argument, which is an instance of `ActionView::Base` (or subclass thereof).

The object you're using outside of the view context is an instance of `Jbuilder` and doesn't have the `#partial!` method, which is why you have the `"partial!"` key in the returned JSON -- it's not treated any differently than any other key.

As far as I know, the only (easy) way to accomplish what you want to do is to use [ActionController::Renderer](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html) (as @Mene said).

```
ApplicationController.render 'path/to/template.jbuilder', locals: {...}, assigns: {...}
```

Comment: do you know how to refer to a template outside of the `views/` dir? I'm just looking to serialize my object for server -> server comms